# Any way to access files like images, audio and video in external storage in iOS 7/8?

Tags: ios

After searching this site and Googling, I get the "No no", but those answers are from 2011/2012. Now it is iOS 8, so I would like to ask again, is it possible to develop apps to access external flash storage like camera kit?

Personally I did not see the API in iOS 8 SDK, but I am wondering maybe Apple does allow this in MFi docs. Well, I don't know....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

iPhones do not provide the possibility to use external flash storage. So the answer is still "no".

Comment: I've just found an interesting thing in [KickStarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/hypershop/isticktm-usb-flash-drive-with-lightning-for-iphone), how did they do it? Can't believe it.